# how to assign value to readonly static field

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, class

I have a field which is static and readonly. The requirement is that the value should be allocated to the field at the login time and after that it should be readonly. How can i achieve this ?

```
  public static class Constant
    {
        public static readonly string name;                

    }
```

Kindly guide.

Comment: This requirement is for a Windows application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class Constant
{
    public static string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name == null)
                name = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("...");
        }
    }
    private static string name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a readonly field you can only set it in the constructor of the class. What you could do is implementing a property only having a getter and exposing a change method that is used during your logon sequence to modify the value. Other Parts of your program can use the property effectivly not allowing them to change the value.

Comment: +1 for addressing the login problem and not just the `static readonly` problem.

Comment: Sure if you can give us a little more background information, is your field in a class that is instantiated during login or does it already exist?

Comment: Beside beeing static, check RedHat´s answer and continue on, you may not want to throw the exception, but I think the idea in generell is what you´re looking for

Answer (score 1):

you need a static constructor

```
public static class Constant
{
    public static readonly string name;

    static Constant()
    {
        name = "abc";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value in the declaration (or constructor) like this:

```
public static class Constant     
{
    public static readonly string name = "MyName";
}
```

`readonly` is sugar for the compiler, telling him, that you don't intend to change the value outside the constructor. If you do so, he will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a static constructor in your static class

```
static Constant()
{
    name = "Name";
}
```